# Наиболее частый элемент массива

Tags: c++

Есть задача

```
Дан массив, состоящий из N целых чисел, упорядоченных по неубыванию.

Определите, какое число встречается в массиве чаще всего.
Выведите одно целое число — наиболее часто встречающийся элемент массива. Если подходящих ответов несколько, выведите максимальный из них.
```

И вот входные/выходные данные

```
входные данные
5
1 2 3 4 5
выходные данные
5

входные данные
8
12 25 25 28 31 31 31 96
выходные данные
31
```

Я написал такой код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
 
 
int main()
{
    vector<int> v;

    int n, e;
    cin>> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> e;
        v.push_back(e);
    }
    
    int maxcount(1), nn(-1);

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        int count(0);

        for (int j = i; j < v.size(); j++)

            if (v[i] == v[j])
                count++;

        if (maxcount < count)
        {
            maxcount = count;
            nn = i;
            
        }
    }
    
    if (nn > -1){
        
        cout << v[nn];
    }
    else
        cout << *v.rbegin();
 
 

    return 0;
}
```

Как я могу вывести максимальный элемент, если таких несколько?

P.S.
Как я понял, если нет повторяющихся, то нужно вывести последний элемент)?

Comment: Возьмите `map`, все будет куда проще...

Answer (score 1):

В условии задачи написано : *"Если подходящих ответов несколько, выведите максимальный из них."*. Это значит, нужно чуток расписать эту ситуацию так :

```
int maxcount(0),...
...
if ( maxcount <= count )
{
  maxcount = count;
  nn = i;        
}
...
cout << v[nn];
```

Если количество совпало с максимальным **ИЛИ** больше, то менять на новое. *Так как у вас цикл движется от маленьких значениях до больших, то конкурент всегда больше.*

Чтобы была возможность правильно выбирать максимальное число, если в числах встречаются отрицательные нужно поставить начальное значение `maxcount = 0`